# Data sent from TinyMCE not saving in proper format

Tags: mysql, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE for saving my data. But when I change the color of the selected text to green and show it as as html the output is:

```
text bla bla bla <span style="color: #99cc00;">Selected word</span> lorem ipsum sads a
```

And after saving in the mysql database it is stored like:

```
&lt;span  #99cc00;&quot;&gt;Selected word&lt;/span&gt;
```

So, as you can see this : `span  #99cc00;&quot;` should be:

```
span=&quot; #99cc00;&quot;
```

But it isn't.

Any idea why the first double quotes are escaped and the equal sign too? How to save them to the database too?

Answer (score 0):

Use the htmlspecialchars function before storing the data in database.

You can see the [tutorial here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

And after fetching the data, when you echoing it use html_entity_decode function. This will convert all in as HTML comes from database.

The tutorial is here: [Tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

Comment: Hmm, it isn;t helping much. THe data are still saved the same way.

Comment: It's not working even if I try: `'body' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['body'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')`

Comment: @klekypetra In database, it will save like same. But when you will fetch the data it will give correct output.

Comment: you don't understand. IT is saved wrong. It is saved like: `&lt;span  #99cc00;&quot;&gt;Selected word&lt;/span&gt;` the decoded echoed output is like: <span #99cc00">Selected word</span> . FOr some reason the equals sign is removed and the quotes.

Comment: use `'body' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['body'])` only. and then check.

Comment: I have previously used that. and it works fine. do that which I am guiding you.

Comment: I tried that first, not working, still saving without the equal sign

Comment: My database is utf8_general_ci including tables.

Comment: use utf8_encode() function to encode the html if your database is utd8.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is disable XSS filtering in CodeIgniter:

```
$this->input->post('textarea', FALSE);
```